# InvalidStateError in firefox private navigation mode

Tags: javascript, here-api

Using the basic example provided here : https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/quick-start.html

When loading the "Complete HTML Example Page" in firefox private navigation mode, the browser console logs three "InvalidStateError" exceptions coming from mapjs-core.js. It seems to be related to indexedDB but it's hard to say as the js code is obfuscated.

Apart of those exceptions, everything seems to work fine, but I wonder if it can have consequences on other features of the Here API. Is there a way to prevent those exception ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *InvalidStateError* is indeed related to *IndexedDB*, and you see this error because, currently, Firefox private browsing mode does not get along with *IndexedDB*. See **[this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781982)** from Mozilla bugtracker for reference.

On [Here WeGo](https://wego.here.com) app, one can see that the state of the map, like the last position, the recent searches and others, are stored in the *localStorage* object. I've yet to find something stored in the IndexedDB database, therefore I wouldn't worry too much, especially if we consider that if the user browses the map in private mode, he probably doesn't expect to recover some state after reopening his browser.